# How to retrieve metrics such as CPU loading, database connections, memory with django-prometheus

Tags: python, django, prometheus, metrics

Is it possible to retrieve CPU info, total database connections and memory info with `django-prometheus`?

After installing `django-prometheus` to my `Django` project `prometheus/metrics` I cannot understand is there any metrics to achieve my goals.

Or it there another ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try to open you exporter web page it should be on jango server. you should know the port. then you will see a list of metrics available for you, then you can go to prometheus and check configuration. Only then you can configure PromQL to build nice grafs